# How do I build a web api url like /owners/xxxx/dogs?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking to build a prototype using ASP.NET Web API 4.0. How do I build the route like the  following URI?

```
/People/PersonId/Dogs

/People/PersonId/Dogs/DogId
```

Where People is the controller, PersonId is an Int, Dogs is the collection of dogs owned by the person, and DogId is an Int of the specific dog.

I also want to have querystring options like,

```
/People/PersonId/Dogs?color=white&activity=walking&location=backyard
```

Comment: Try to keep things simple. Why not just return a person based on it's id. In this person-object, the client gets a collection of dogs and it's properties. Let the client decide what to use. You can use `AttributeRouting` for making complex URI's. You can get the querystring in the URI like this `Request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString()["color"]`

Comment: @JeanD - Returning the person, or person's dogs, object graph will likely result in a large amount of data being returned to the client. The real application is not about people and dogs.

Comment: Perhaps OData is an option????